# Unable to store verbose output of curl command to variable in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, scripting

I want to search this verbose output to get the http code which in this case would be 200 or "HTTP/1.1 200 OK". I am able to get the true output returned by the server, but am wondering why I cannot get this verbose output.

```
curl www.google.com -v
 *   Trying 74.125.196.106:80...
 * Connected to www.google.com (74.125.196.106) port 80 (#0)
 > GET / HTTP/1.1
 > Host: www.google.com
 > User-Agent: curl/7.72.0
 > Accept: */*
 >
 * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
 < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I am currently testing with this code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('curl www.google.com -v') do set _CmdResult=%%a
ECHO %_CmdResult%
```

Comment: The verbose output is being written to standard error. `curl -v www.google.com 2>&1 |findstr /C:"200 OK"`

Comment: Since I want to set the result into a variable, I added in the command like this:
`for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('curl www.google.com -v 2>&1 ^|findstr /C:"200 OK"') do set _CmdResult=%%a`
But I get an error: 2>&1 was unexpected at this time.

Comment: You must escape all the special characters which includes the redirection and ampersand.